# How to delete string other than pattern?

Tags: awk, sed, grep, cat

I have a m3u file as below. I want to delete all strings except the pattern and next first line. or save the pattern and the next first line as another file.

**Patterns group-title="TR ULUSAL" , group-title="TR HABER" , group-title="TR BELGESEL"**
Raw data:

```
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="TRT HD 1080" tvg-logo="http://url/tr/trt.png" group-title="TR ULUSAL",TRT HD 1080
http://xxx.xx:xx/xx/xx/123

#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="THRILLER 16 Blocks" tvg-logo="http://url/Blocks.jpg" group-title="DEUTSCHE FILME",THRILLER 16 Blocks
http://xxx.xx:xx/xx/xx/632.mkv

#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="TRT HD 720" tvg-logo="http://url/trt.png" group-title="TR ULUSAL",TRT HD 720
http://xxx.xx:xx/xx/xx/218

#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="CNN TURK 1080" tvg-logo="http://url/cnnturkhd.png" group-title="TR HABER",CNN TURK 1080
http://xxx.xx:xx/xx/xx/926

#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="THRILLER 28 Weeks Later" tvg-logo="http://url/tr/Later.jpg" group-title="RUSSIA",THRILLER 28 Weeks Later
http://xxx.xx:xx/xx/xx/4805.mkv

#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="THRILLER 16 Blocks" tvg-logo="http://url/Blocks.jpg" group-title="TR DUBLAJ FILM",THRILLER 16 Blocks
http://xxx.xx:xx/xx/xx/632.mkv

#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="TRT BELGESEL HD 720" tvg-logo="http://url/trtb.png" group-title="TR BELGESEL",TRT BELGESEL 720
http://xxx.xx:xx/xx/xx/218
```

The result I am expecting is:

```
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="TRT HD 1080" tvg-logo="http://url/tr/trt.png" group-title="TR ULUSAL",TRT HD 1080
http://xxx.xx:xx/xx/xx/123

#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="TRT HD 720" tvg-logo="http://url/trt.png" group-title="TR ULUSAL",TRT HD 720
http://xxx.xx:xx/xx/xx/218

#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="CNN TURK 1080" tvg-logo="http://url/cnnturkhd.png" group-title="TR HABER",CNN TURK 1080
http://xxx.xx:xx/xx/xx/926

#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="TRT BELGESEL 720" tvg-logo="http://url/trtb.png" group-title="TR BELGESEL",TRT BELGESEL 720
http://xxx.xx:xx/xx/xx/218
```

Answer (score 1):

In `sed` you would used extended regular expression with option `-E`:

```
sed -E '/group-title="TR (ULUSAL|HABER|BELGESEL)"/!d;n;n'
```

The `()` around the `ULUSAL|HABER|BELGESEL` make sure the `|` only applies for the patterns inside.

A line with neither pattern (the `!` behind the pattern) gets deleted. All other lines (those with the patterns) execute the `n;n`, so the line itself gets printed, the `n`ext one as well and the `n`ext empty line after it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file is called `inputfile`, and the output should be stored in `outputfile`:

```
grep --no-group-separator -A 2 -E \
"group-title=\"TR ULUSAL\"|group-title=\"TR HABER\"|group-title=\"TR BELGESEL\"" \
inputfile > outputfile
```

This works by using extended regular expressions (`-E`), and after-context (`-A`).

Comment: Both suggestions working great. Thank you.